# SQL to Text Tools

Tags: openai-api

There are a lot of text-to-sql translators out there (langchain for example), are there any sql-to-text translators?

I'd like to be able to feed in a random sql snippet as well as the sql varient (postgres, oracle, t-sql etc.) and see an explanation.

For example, given
`select count(*) from baseball_players` `postgres` I'd like to see something like

`Count the number of baseball players in MLB today`

I've looked at langchain, and hugging face with no luck.  Here's an example of a website that is doing what I'm describing.

https://www.text2sql.ai/

Comment: _Ostensibly_, because SQL is declarative it's meant to be directly readable (in practice, it isn't, but it's impossible to tersely explain any SQL query in fewer words than the query itself, fwiw).

Comment: I'm more thinking about helping non-technical users understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you don't want an arbitrarily terse explanation, but a "plain language" explanation. I know current chatGPT is capable of this as well (but it's currently blocked from where I am). So here is an example from BingAI:

"*could you please describe what this does: select count(*)::numeric from baseball_players*"

**response:**

Sure! ***The given statement is a SQL query that counts the total number of rows in the baseball_players table and returns the result as a numeric value. The ::numeric part of the query casts the result of count(*) to a numeric data type.*** Is there anything else you would like to know?

note I placed postgres specific syntax into the query

Comment: ChatGPT isn't perfect though - it's easy to trip it up and get incorrect responses if you have a really gnarly and convoluted query, use very new features and syntax, using SQL dialect-specific _idioms_, or anything that requires knowing the underlying table design. For example, I tried asking ChatGPT to explain `SELECT ISNULL( COUNT(*), 0 ) AS cnt FROM myTable` and it incorrectly said that `COUNT(*)` returns `NULL` when a table is empty and didn't explain that `ISNULL` was used in this-case to force the resultset column to be reported as `NOT NULL` which is needed due to SQL Server's quirks.

Comment: I didn't suggest it was perfect, and very convoluted queries will be a problem I suspect for any generalised tool. Not sure you need the ISNULL btw see https://dbfiddle.uk/EYDtcLCo

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. Didn't realize it was that straightforward.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work quite well - at least on simple queries.